# How can I auto-break lines based on the size of the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple mock console web page that's supposed to look like a unix command line. The idea is to be able to scroll to animate the typing and outputs, and be able to scroll up to "scrub" the playback of the scroll animation.

My problem is that I'm using a fixed div to keep the console text in the same spot as you scroll through the document, but I need a way to be able to hide the overflow and autoscroll to the bottom of the div. So for example, when someone gets to the "cat log2" command, and the output for that spits out, if their window is shorter than the output, it should push everything at the top of the screen off the screen to the top, and scroll to the bottom so the user can see the last bit of output (just like command line output in Putty).

I have a half-baked solution developed (in a different example than the one below) where I check after output is triggered if the bottom-most spans are visible (using a separate JQuery library), and then hide the top-most spans depending on that. But I feel like there has to be an easier way, **particularly with CSS alone**. I would love something simpler, and something that is more robust, as my Javascript solution is taking a while to work out the kinks on various screen sizes.

Also if you're curious, I'm using the Skrollr plugin to create the animation effect (which is where the data-____ attributes come into play).

Here is my concept:

http://codepen.io/nicholaswilson/pen/qbGByj

HTML:

```
<div>
<div id="scroll-div" class="pinned"></div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.spacer{
  height:300px;
}
.pinned{
  position: fixed;
  left: 15;
  top: 15;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  color: white;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, "Consolas", "Courier New", "Courier";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #30353A;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

JS:

```
var skrollrobj = skrollr.init();

//var scroll_speed_in = 100;

var console_data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "order": "1",
  "class": "prompt",
  "text": "nickw@localhost ~ "
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "order": "2",
  "class": "typing",
  "text": "ls -l"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "order": "3",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log1"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "order": "4",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log2"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "order": "5",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log3"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "order": "6",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log4"
}, {
  "id": "7",
  "order": "7",
  "class": "prompt",
  "text": "nickw@localhost ~ "
}, {
  "id": "8",
  "order": "8",
  "class": "typing",
  "text": "cat log1"
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "order": "9",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "hello world."
}, {
  "id": "10",
  "order": "10",
  "class": "prompt",
  "text": "nickw@localhost ~ "
}, {
  "id": "11",
  "order": "12",
  "class": "typing",
  "text": "cat log2"
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "order": "9",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue est ante, eu semper ex eleifend ut. In at tincidunt diam, sit amet tristique lacus. Etiam iaculis dignissim orci, non tristique sapien lacinia quis. Donec massa nulla, volutpat quis tempor a, varius laoreet leo. In id ligula nulla. Nam enim nulla, placerat quis dolor quis, aliquet vehicula nulla. Aliquam ut metus volutpat, dignissim nisi ut, sollicitudin mi. Mauris ut euismod quam, non dignissim lorem. Phasellus euismod lobortis volutpat. Nunc in molestie dui. Praesent quis lectus viverra, consequat orci ut, dignissim metus. Phasellus sed mi vel nisi pellentesque mattis."
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log(getSpansFromString("HI DOUCHEBAG"));
  initializeScroller($("#scroll-div"), console_data, 100);

})

function getSpansFromString(input_string) {
  var retVal = [];
  var split_string = input_string.split('');

  for (var i = 0; i < split_string.length; i++) {
    //retVal = retVal + "<span>" + split_string[i] + "</span>";
    var this_element = $("<span>" + split_string[i] + "</span>");
    //this_element.attr("data-100", "display:inline");
    //this_element.attr('data-' + scroll_line * scroll_speed, 'display:inline');
    retVal[i] = this_element;
    //retVal[i] = "<span>" + split_string[i] + "</span>";
  }

  //var element = $(retVal[0]);
  //element.attr('data-info', '222');
  //console.log(element);

  return retVal;
}

function initializeScroller(element, data, scroll_speed) {
  var scroll_line = 0;
  var last_class;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      element.append('<span data-0="display:inline" ' + 'data-' + i * scroll_speed + '="display:inline"' + '>' + data[i].text + '</span>');
    } else {
      if (data[i].class == "prompt" && data[i].order != 1) {
        element.append("<br/><br/>");
      }
      if (data[i].class == "output") {

        if (last_class == "output") {
          element.append("<br/>");
        } else {
          element.append("<br/><br/>");
        }
      }
      if (data[i].class == "typing"){
          var spans = getSpansFromString(data[i].text);
          for (var s = 0; s < spans.length; s++){
            var this_element = $(spans[s][0]);
            this_element.attr("data-0", "display:none");
            this_element.attr("data-" + scroll_line * scroll_speed, "display:inline");
            element.append(this_element[0].outerHTML);
            scroll_line++;
          }
      } else {
      element.append('<span data-0="display:none" ' + 'data-' + scroll_line * scroll_speed + '="display:inline"' + '>' + data[i].text + '</span>');
      }
    }
    skrollrobj.refresh();
    last_class = data[i].class;
    if (data[i].class != "output") {
      scroll_line++;
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So to clarify the issue - If I have the window shrunk, like on a mobile display, when I get to "cat log2" for example, the output is off the page:

[image: output falls below screen]

I'm looking for it to automatically shift the stuff at the top (nickw@localhost ~ ls -l" and the appropriate number of lines from the ls output off the screen to the top, and move the stuff that's off the screen, onto it.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but can't you just make .pinned{ bottom:15; } ?

Comment: Hmm... Yeah I'm not sure I'm explaining it right. I just tried that, and it didn't work. Let me edit my question just a bit...

Comment: Does the image help explain it a bit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwbWKN

This is as far as I could get ^

**It doesn't work if the screen is smaller than the initial load height which is around 270px** The height is due to the `<br>`s that are there on load, so if you could make these also get loaded on scroll it should fix that issue!

`#scroll-div-wrapper` - Fixed positioning with an overflow hidden.

`.pinned` - Used flexbox to align this to the bottom of the scroll-div-wrapper so when it becomes taller than the parent it will stick to the bottom.

```js
var skrollrobj = skrollr.init();

//var scroll_speed_in = 100;

var console_data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "order": "1",
  "class": "prompt",
  "text": "nickw@localhost ~ "
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "order": "2",
  "class": "typing",
  "text": "ls -l"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "order": "3",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log1"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "order": "4",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log2"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "order": "5",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log3"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "order": "6",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "-rw-r----- 1 nick developer 1564 Jan 19 2016 log4"
}, {
  "id": "7",
  "order": "7",
  "class": "prompt",
  "text": "nickw@localhost ~ "
}, {
  "id": "8",
  "order": "8",
  "class": "typing",
  "text": "cat log1"
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "order": "9",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "hello world."
}, {
  "id": "10",
  "order": "10",
  "class": "prompt",
  "text": "nickw@localhost ~ "
}, {
  "id": "11",
  "order": "12",
  "class": "typing",
  "text": "cat log2"
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "order": "9",
  "class": "output",
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue est ante, eu semper ex eleifend ut. In at tincidunt diam, sit amet tristique lacus. Etiam iaculis dignissim orci, non tristique sapien lacinia quis. Donec massa nulla, volutpat quis tempor a, varius laoreet leo. In id ligula nulla. Nam enim nulla, placerat quis dolor quis, aliquet vehicula nulla. Aliquam ut metus volutpat, dignissim nisi ut, sollicitudin mi. Mauris ut euismod quam, non dignissim lorem. Phasellus euismod lobortis volutpat. Nunc in molestie dui. Praesent quis lectus viverra, consequat orci ut, dignissim metus. Phasellus sed mi vel nisi pellentesque mattis."
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log(getSpansFromString("HI DOUCHEBAG"));
  initializeScroller($("#scroll-div"), console_data, 100);
  
})

function getSpansFromString(input_string) {
  var retVal = [];
  var split_string = input_string.split('');

  for (var i = 0; i < split_string.length; i++) {
    //retVal = retVal + "<span>" + split_string[i] + "</span>";
    var this_element = $("<span>" + split_string[i] + "</span>");
    //this_element.attr("data-100", "display:inline");
    //this_element.attr('data-' + scroll_line * scroll_speed, 'display:inline');
    retVal[i] = this_element;
    //retVal[i] = "<span>" + split_string[i] + "</span>";
  }

  //var element = $(retVal[0]);
  //element.attr('data-info', '222');
  //console.log(element);

  return retVal;
}

function initializeScroller(element, data, scroll_speed) {
  var scroll_line = 0;
  var last_class;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      element.append('<span data-0="display:inline" ' + 'data-' + i * scroll_speed + '="display:inline"' + '>' + data[i].text + '</span>');
    } else {
      if (data[i].class == "prompt" && data[i].order != 1) {
        element.append("<br/><br/>");
      }
      if (data[i].class == "output") {

        if (last_class == "output") {
          element.append("<br/>");
        } else {
          element.append("<br/><br/>");
        }
      }
      if (data[i].class == "typing"){
          var spans = getSpansFromString(data[i].text);
          for (var s = 0; s < spans.length; s++){
            var this_element = $(spans[s][0]);
            this_element.attr("data-0", "display:none");
            this_element.attr("data-" + scroll_line * scroll_speed, "display:inline");
            element.append(this_element[0].outerHTML);
            scroll_line++;
          }
      } else {
      element.append('<span data-0="display:none" ' + 'data-' + scroll_line * scroll_speed + '="display:inline"' + '>' + data[i].text + '</span>');
      }
    }
    skrollrobj.refresh();
    last_class = data[i].class;
    if (data[i].class != "output") {
      scroll_line++;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.spacer{
  height:300px;
}
#scroll-div-wrapper {
  position:fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  bottom:15px;
  right:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
}
.pinned{
  overflow:auto;
  width:120%;
  min-height:100%;
  flex: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
body {
  color: white;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, "Consolas", "Courier New", "Courier";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #30353A;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll-div-wrapper">
  <div id="scroll-div" class="pinned"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Dang, thank you. I've never used Flexbox, but it looks like I'll want to learn it. This is exactly what I needed - And yeah, I should have no problem incorporating those br's into the Skrollr. Thanks!